# Age Calculation error in laravel 5+?

Tags: php, laravel-5, date

Controller

```
static function show()
{
    //
    $output = '';
    $result = DB::table('PersonalDetail')
            ->get();
    foreach ($result as $key ) {
        $dob = Carbon::$key->DOB;

        // We need to compare the user's date of birth with today's date.
        $now =Carbon::now();

        // Calculate the time difference between the two dates.
        $difference = $now->diff($dob);

        // Get the difference in years, as we are looking for the user's age.
        $age = $difference->y;

        $output .= '<p>Age:-'.$age.' </p>';
    }

    return ($output);
}
```

View Blade

Call to a member function diff() on string (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WedLaravel/WedLara/resources/views/pages/ViewPeo.blade.php)

I Got this error , I have try lot

Comment: Use [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), since it's built into Laravel and gives you a lot of functions. `$now` as you're creating it is a string, not a DateTime or Carbon object.

Comment: Sorry ,I didn't get you point .can you explain ? @aynber

Comment: When you create `$now`, it just contains the `2018-06-06`. What you need to do is create it as `$now = Carbon::now()`. Then you can use the functions shown in the docs I linked. You'll probably also need to cast `$dob` as a Carbon object as well.

Comment: Still not working @aynber

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show what you have now?

Comment: updated @aynber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate differences in dates using Carbon, you must cast both dates as Carbon objects, and then use the methods provided:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$dob = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $key->dob);
$diff = $now->diff($dob);
```

You'll then have a DateInterval object that will give you the different intervals, so you can use `$d->y`. Since it's Carbon, there are other methods you can use, such as

```
$now->diffInDays($dob);
$now->diffForHumans($dob);
```

Comment: 'throw new InvalidArgumentException(implode(PHP_EOL, $lastErrors['errors'])); ' i got this error

Comment: That's an odd error, and shouldn't come from any of this code if `$key->dob` is properly formatted. If it's not in `Y-m-d` format, then you'll need to adjust the format. Otherwise, post the full error message.

Comment: Ya, date Format is correct  full error here  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Data missing (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WedLaravel/WedLara/resources/views/pages/ViewPeo.blade.php)

Comment: Add `Log::info($key->dob);` before `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d' $key->dob);` then look at the log file to see what the format is. Data missing means that the datestamp format isn't correct.

Comment: where can see log file @aynber

Comment: [2018-06-07 01:52:17] local.INFO: 2018-05-24  output like this

Comment: Thank you Sir . Some row of DOB got null value before that's got error

Comment: You're welcome! I figured it might be a null issue. (And not everyone here is a sir, by the way...)